# How do I yarn ignore a package that requires an older version of node?

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

I'm trying to switch from npm to yarn.

After using the `yarn` command to do so, I get an error message saying that
*tags@0.6.3: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "5.8.0". Got "12.0.0"*

However, i don't want to use an old version of node. Instead, I want to yarn ignore the tags package. How do I do that? Do I need to create a file or is there a command?

Comment: if you want to ignore the file from git commit just use `.gitignore` file.

Comment: You can ignore entire directories, just by including their paths and putting a / on the end:

```.gitignore

node_modules/
logs/

```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the node version check with the `--ignore-engines` option

```
yarn import --ignore-engines
```